# Phonegap/cordova command line gives code signing error, xcode works fine. (IOS)

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

When entering the command

```
phonegap run ios
```

I get the following error:

```
=== BUILD TARGET F-Securities OF PROJECT F-Securities WITH CONFIGURATION Debug ===

Check dependencies
Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and         private key pair) matching the team ID “XXXXXXXX” were found.
CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 8.1'
```

However XCode sees and correctly builds and deploys the app. I'd like to be able to use the command     line, but it does not work anymore.

I am a part of two teams (myself, and the firm i am working for). I am agent at my team, and admin on my firms team. I have downloaded provisioning profiles and certificates for both teams.

Comment: Your errors explaining your answer. You need to add provisional profile for the application. Read this - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW4

Comment: @Kampai This is for development, and not distribution. The only ad-hoc provisioning profile I can create is for distribution. I have development provisioning profiles installed, and XCode manges to use them properly, but the command line won't.

And using ad-hoc seems like a workaround, because that's intended for users not being a part of the team.

Comment: It's clearly visible that issue is related with application identity. I mean your application identity conflict some where. Please double check that you have enter proper team ID and bundle identifier is correct.

Comment: Same issue, and as @ErlendEllingsen state, ad-hoc is intend for users not being a part of the team.  Xcode is able to deploy the app and debug it, but not cordova run ios