# phonegap run ios gives shell.js internal error (Mac, Cordova)

Tags: ios, node.js, macos, cordova, npm

This is the console output that I get when trying to execute "phonegap run ios", which executes "cordova run ios".

```
ErlendMBPrivate:fsecapp erlendellingsen$ phonegap run ios 
[phonegap] executing 'cordova run ios'...
shell.js: internal error

Error: EPERM, operation not permitted '/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/jobb/fsecapp/platforms/ios/F-Securities/config.xml'
at Object.fs.chmodSync (fs.js:821:18)
at copyFileSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:41:6)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:198:5
at Array.forEach (native)
at Object._cp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/shelljs/src/cp.js:157:11)
at Object.cp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/shelljs/src/common.js:186:23)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:74:23
at Array.map (native)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/prepare.js:65:40
at _fulfilled (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:787:54)
```

Now. I understand somewhat that there seems to be a chmod-problem. However. All of the folders that are named in the output log, are all accessible, readable and writeable by all users. I have chmodded all the folders.

**More importantly**
When I enter sudo-mode, there are no internal error. However. When authenticated as root, and using "sudo -i" when executing the command, the command line is unable to find *any valid signing identites*

If you don't understand the problems I get when executing as sudo, please see the StackOverflow-question I posted last week: [Phonegap/cordova command line gives code signing error, xcode works fine. (IOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187232/phonegap-cordova-command-line-gives-code-signing-error-xcode-works-fine-ios)

Answer (score 2):

Phonegap (through Cordova) has **insufficient permissions** on the project folder.

To fix this issue is necessary to modify the project folder permissions in order to make the `config.xml` file **writable** by Cordova.

Normally Phonegap is run by the user, Cordova is invoked by Phonegap so in order to give Cordova permissions is necessary to give the user the ownership of the project folder. This can be achieved as follows:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) "/Applications/XAMPP/htdocs/jobb/fsecapp"
```

[source](https://github.com/Wakanda/wakanda-issues/issues/73#issuecomment-221559574)